# NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f5b25bc24e0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] ',))

Tags: python, django, django-models, deployment, django-rest-framework

I have kyc form and when fill all fields and click on submit button then I see the following traceback.

```
Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/kyc/kyc

Django Version: 3.1.4
Python Version: 3.8.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'accounts',
 'bootstrap3',
 'profiles',
 'django_countries',
 'kyc']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\dotescrow_env\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\dotescrow_env\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 96, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\dotescrow_env\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 86, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)

During handling of the above exception ([WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it), another exception occurred:
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\dotescrow_env\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\dotescrow_env\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 394, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\dotescrow_env\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 234, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\dotescrow_env\lib\http\client.py", line 1255, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\dotescrow_env\lib\http\client.py", line 1301, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\dotescrow_env\lib\http\client.py", line 1250, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\dotescrow_env\lib\http\client.py", line 1010, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\dotescrow_env\lib\http\client.py", line 950, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\dotescrow_env\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 200, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\dotescrow_env\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 181, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(

During handling of the above exception (<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001CDC237AC70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it), another exception occurred:
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\dotescrow_env\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\dotescrow_env\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\dotescrow_env\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 573, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))

During handling of the above exception (HTTPConnectionPool(host='93.115.29.78', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/token/mainnet/address/0x779d4E727232fF0b0B20c7926430DBDBC03aE84C/0xaf79C4c4106b7C35c2FeC72D130783524f821D89 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001CDC237AC70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))), another exception occurred:
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\dotescrow_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\dotescrow_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\dotescrow_env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\dotescrow_env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\mixins.py", line 52, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\dotescrow_env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\dotescrow_env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 172, in post
    return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\dotescrow_env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 141, in post
    if form.is_valid():
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\dotescrow_env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 177, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\dotescrow_env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 172, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\dotescrow_env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 375, in full_clean
    self._clean_form()
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\dotescrow_env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 402, in _clean_form
    cleaned_data = self.clean()
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\nitin_pro\dotescrow\kyc\forms.py", line 119, in clean
    result = requests.get(url, headers={'Authorization':'2RxsiIvEtuaPxxvP6eTs98fr55K4xJye3IqEJWhk'})
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\dotescrow_env\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\dotescrow_env\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\dotescrow_env\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\dotescrow_env\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\dotescrow_env\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)

Exception Type: ConnectionError at /kyc/kyc
Exception Value: HTTPConnectionPool(host='93.115.29.78', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/token/mainnet/address/0x779d4E727232fF0b0B20c7926430DBDBC03aE84C/0xaf79C4c4106b7C35c2FeC72D130783524f821D89 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001CDC237AC70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
```

You can also see traceback on this link: https://dpaste.com/2HETHPFVU
I know its terrible looking error, I don't know how to fix it, or what might be the reason of this error.

Comment: Please do not offer to serial upvote someone who helps you. This is not considered honest behaviour on Stack Overflow, and that level of serial voting would be automatically reversed by an fraud detection script anyway.